# at-rule or selector expectedcss(css-ruleorselectorexpected)

Tags: angular, deployment, angularbuild

When I try to build angular application and open the files in dist folder like index.html and try running these file on a live server it gives me this error

```
at-rule or selector expectedcss(css-ruleorselectorexpected)
```

specially on the lines contains

```
@charset "UTF-8"
```

here's a screenshot
[image]

And also when I try to see what happen in the console it gives me different errors here's a screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've found an answer it's not a code error it's just the text editor doesn't accept this lines of code

```
@charset "UTF-8"
```

so to solve this just go to VSC settings->Extensions->CSS Language Feature->css
and uncheck the css:Validate option